# Wild card ssl on Apache CentOS 7

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4, https

I have purchased WILDCARD ssl certificate from godaddy. I've used this certificate to couple of servers without generating csr.

Now i have a question. Can i install this existing certificate to the Apache on CentOS 7 ?

With self-signed certificate i can run https on apache. By mentionin private key and crt file. But in this situation there is no private key. I have already had certificate. And i want to install it to the Apache. Have anybody done before ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the file you have with a text editor. Are there two parts in it?

Answer (score 0):

For apache and in general use of certificate (independently if its wildcard or not) you need the private key. Otherwise you can't decrypt the certificate. So check again about the private key.
BTW you can check if the file you have is combining both certificates. You can check it by inspecting your file and search for `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`. If you have both of them your file contain signed public key (certificate) and private key.

For apache you will need also the chain of root certificates of your CA (they are usually provided on the CA web site)

Comment: It might well be a combined certificate OP has.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, maybe you mean file, which combine two parts? There is no such thing as combined certificate!

Comment: Got me. To be more precise: it could be a PEM containing both parts.

Comment: Romeo You are right.
When using a wildcard certificate on multiple servers, there’s one step you’ll need to take when installing the certificate on each server: uploading your private key.

Your private key is created and saved on your server when you generate the CSR. Since you only complete that step on one server, you’ll need to copy your private key to each additional server when you install the certificate.